# Dealing with Expired Licenses?

Tags: c#, .net, licensing

How should we deal with application licenses which are expired. I have created a .NET application and some encrypted license files for different roles with expiration data inside license file. The problem is, when a license is expired and user changes back system (computer) date to some older date, the license becomes valid again.
I have found that this problem also exists with microsoft products (e.g. Visual Studio)

So what should we do with expired licenses to avoid that hack?

Comment: I think it belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your app notices the app expires, it should no longer check the date as part of the security routine - you should instead set a flag someplace, perhaps buried deep in the registry or in some non-obvious file/location that flags the app as having become expired; so that an expired license doesn't automatically un-expire when the date changes - thats just too easy.

Also, if possible, consider using an internet based clock to check the time / date, not the users PC.

Just know that whatever you do, its not going to stop everyone.

Comment: A simple process monitor will show in two minutes what are the registry key/file that are accessed by the application. This will be very easy to defect.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if Microsoft was not able to actually protect their products, it's because it's not possible. And as competent as you can be, don't expect to find the magic bullet that will protect your application. **You have to live with this fact. Your application may (will?) be hacked**.

I can only suggest you to create very well build applications, to encourage the users to buy the application instead of pirating it.

Some users are ok to paid nice applications, but not poor applications or applications with too many protections.

The crackers will always be able to crack the application. You may keep a simple licencing solution, to avoid the wide hack, but not more. **Put more efforts in applications features than trying to protect it**. You will sell more apps if the app is good.

A side note: .Net application are far more easier to hack, because the binaries are easily reverse engineered using some tools (Reflector, ILSpy, etC.)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Photoshop is very good software, it doesn't stop it from being widely pirated. Etc.

Comment: That's the point! Photoshop is a great software, widely cracked but also widely **sold**. A fair design will buy the software, as it will help him in its works. And if a solution would exists, Adobe with its cash firepower would have implemented it. What I mean is that cracking the software can't be avoided. And accepting that to put effort in software features is preferable to sold more.

Comment: Reflector ... yes that tool can break everything up. But for that we can obfuscate the dlls.

Comment: Obfuscation raises the complexity of the reverse engineering, but won't avoid it. It's especially true if the code rely on standard .Net licencing components. The hacker can track down any reference to this component, even if the variable and methods names are obfuscated. But of course, it's a lot more difficult